Sewer pump check valve gurgling noise
Just replaced the stock Everbilt check valve that was making loud clunk at the end of cycle. This new one eliminated the clunking, however a new gurgling sound can be heard when the pump first turns on. It's air I presume. (This was not happening with the other check valve.)
I do have a weep hole drilled according to the pump manual, about 3 inches above the pump discharge.
Is this operation acceptable? The noise isn't bothersome, just wanted to make sure it's not detrimental to anything
Thanks!
https://youtube.com/shorts/ivRctMNFkck?si=Xa277usEvA5LjCu3
